# How can I fix Address boundary error in C?

Tags: c

I'm new to C,and want to write a simple program that takes a user input and prints it out a specific amount of times back to them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char* str[100];
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    int amount;
    *p = amount;
    int i;

    printf("\nType anything!\n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("\nHow many times?\n");
    scanf("%d", amount);
    for (i=0; i<=amount; i++) {
         printf("%s", str);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

It works fine,until after pressing entering the amount of times,when the program crashes with the Fish shell saying "fish: “./a.out” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)".

Address boundary error tells me that maybe I haven't allocated memory for something,but how would I go about doing that? I've tried using malloc with a pointer pointed at `amount` but it doesnt seemed to have solved anything.

Comment: Also enable warnings, e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` command line parameter for `gcc` or `clang` as compiler. The warnings are going to tell you where and what the problem is here.

Comment: What's `p` for? It is unused.

Comment: `scanf("%d", amount);` should be `scanf("%d", &amount);` That's the reason for the error.

Comment: `*p = amount;` is using an uninitialized variable.

Comment: pointer. i tried using it for allocating memory for ``amount``

Comment: Just declaring `int amount` allocates memory for `amount`.

Comment: Note that if you fix the `scanf()` call and type `1` as the number of times, your loop will print the data twice.  (Change `<=` to `<` — this is the standard C idiom.)  Also note that the data will be printed multiple times on a single line — you probably want a newline `\n` in the format: `printf("%s\n", str);`.

Comment: Thank you! adding & before ``amount`` fixed it.

Comment: Any tutorial on using `scanf()` should show the correct way to use it.

Comment: `int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);` and following `*p = amount;` are redundant and both of them can be removed.

Comment: `printf("%s", str);` --> `printf("%s", *str);`

Answer (score 4):

It's remarkable how many issues there are in such a short chunk of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[100];
    int amount;

    printf("\nType any word!\n");
    if (scanf("%99s", str) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read a string\n");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("\nHow many times?\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &amount) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read an integer\n");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
         printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- The signature of `main()` is a full prototype.
- The type of `str` is corrected (or, at least, changed and made usable).
- The code related to `p` and `malloc()` is not needed.
- The variable `i` is moved into the `for` loop (assumes a C99 or later compiler; if not available, what you had was OK).
- Change "anything" to "any word" because `%s` skips white space and then reads non-spaces up to the next white space.
- Limit the amount of input to prevent overflows.
- Report if there's a problem reading the string and exit.
- ***Fix the `scanf()` to pass `&amount`*** (key change).
- Check for success reading `amount` and report failure and exit.
- Define `i` in the loop control (C99).
- If the user requests one copy, only print one copy (change `<=` to `<` — that's an idiomatic C loop now).
- Output newline after each word.  There are other ways to present the data, including the one chosen originally, but you should at least end the output with a newline.